# Subscribe to a simple event sent from server in Meteor

Tags: meteor

Sometimes I want to send simple events from the server to all clients in Meteor without having to deal with Collections - I feel like there must be some easy way to do this but I haven't managed to find it.

I want something like:

**Server**

```
connection.send("messageForAllUsers", {text: "Hello"});
```

**Client**

```
connection.subscribe("messageForAllUsers", function(result){
    alert(result.text);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a meteor stream package which might be what you are needing.
http://arunoda.github.io/meteor-streams/communication-patterns.html#streaming_private_page

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: http://meteorcapture.com/publishing-anything/

I think at the end of the day, collections is the easiest and most straightforward way to go when it comes to Meteor.